# Load image faster

Tags: php, image, optimization

lately, I'm searching about optimizing heavily loaded sites with a lot of images and I found this to optimize images:

- resizing image
- compressing image
- and using CDN

but I found the format of the images is important too and I don't know between JPG, Webp, and PNG which one is better fit in this situation for optimizing. how can I choose between them?

Comment: CDN: what does that mean ?

Comment: JPEG makes lossy compression, so compresses more.

Comment: I mean a server with the purpose of storing and retrieving resources -  a download server @YvesDaoust